# Display list in table or grid format in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-content-types

I am creating a simple site in drupal, in which i have several pages. I have that page called Notification as you can see in the sample image. First i want a feature by which Admin can upload some data like Name or title, A pdf file etc, any one who visits the site will go the page and click on any pdf link and download or view the pdf.
I have tried Contents Types, Views for that purpose, but I am not able to achieve it as it got very confusing. Please any help would be appreciated.

[image]

The table like structure is what i want, its just done in paint. It will be helpful if anyone can provide a step by step guied to create this type of structure. The table will display latest n records uploaded by Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to create a new content type (e.g. `Notification`)
2. Add field `Description` with type `File` for `Notification` content type (you can use base field `Title` of `Node` as `Name` so you don't need to create another one)
   [image]
3. Create a View of content (e.g. `Notification`), then add fields and settings as below:
   [image]
4. Add some `Notification` from `Add content` screen (`/node/add/notification`)
   [image]
5. Result (Page `/notification`)
   [image]